# Перестал работать поиск по товарам в админ панели

Tags: php, mysql

День назад поиск по товарам работал а теперь не работает ,не могу понять что случилось . Даже перестал работать поиск в других каталогах где установлена админ панель для другой базы данных. Подскажите пожалуйста что могло произойти и где копать ?

Это мой код где встроен поисковик:

```
<?php
    include_once('includes/connect_database.php'); 
    include_once('functions.php'); 
?>

<div id="content" class="container col-md-12">
        <?php 
$sql_query = "SELECT Category_ID, Category_name 
            FROM tbl_category 
            ORDER BY Category1_ID ASC";

        $stmt_category = $connect->stmt_init();
        if($stmt_category->prepare($sql_query)) {   
            // Execute query
            $stmt_category->execute();
            // store result 
            $stmt_category->store_result();
            $stmt_category->bind_result($category_data['Category_ID'], 
                $category_data['Category_name']
                );      
        }
        ?>

<div id="content" class="container">
    <?php 
        // create object of functions class
        $function = new functions;

        // create array variable to store data from database
        $data = array();

        if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){    
            // check value of keyword variable
            $keyword = $function->sanitize($_GET['keyword']);
            $bind_keyword = "%".$keyword."%";
        }else{
            $keyword = "";
            $bind_keyword = $keyword;
        }

        // get currency symbol from setting table
        $sql_query = "SELECT Value 
                FROM tbl_setting 
                WHERE Variable = 'Currency'";

        $stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
        if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {    
            // Execute query
            $stmt->execute();
            // store result 
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($currency);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
        }   

        // get all data from menu table and category table
        if(empty($keyword)){
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity 
                    FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                    WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND c.Category_ID IN (47,50,48,52) 
                    ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC";
        }else{
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
                    FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                    WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND Menu_name LIKE ? 
                    ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC";
        }

        $stmt = $connect->stmt_init();
        if($stmt->prepare($sql_query)) {    
            // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
            if(!empty($keyword)){
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $bind_keyword);
            }
            // Execute query
            $stmt->execute();
            // store result 
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($data['Menu_ID'], 
                    $data['Menu_name'], 
                    $data['Category_name'],
                    $data['Price'], 
                    $data['Serve_for'],
                    $data['Menu_image'],
                    $data['Quantity']
                    );

            // get total records
            $total_records = $stmt->num_rows;
        }

        // check page parameter
        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }else{
            $page = 1;
        }

        // number of data that will be display per page     
        $offset = 5;

        //lets calculate the LIMIT for SQL, and save it $from
        if ($page){
            $from   = ($page * $offset) - $offset;
        }else{
            //if nothing was given in page request, lets load the first page
            $from = 0;  
        }

        // get all data from reservation table
        if(empty($keyword)){
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
                    FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                    WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND c.Category_ID IN (47,50,48,52)  
                    ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
        }else{
            $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Category_name, Price, Serve_for, Menu_image, Quantity  
                    FROM tbl_menu m, tbl_category c
                    WHERE m.Category_ID = c.Category_ID AND Menu_name LIKE ? 
                    ORDER BY m.Menu_ID DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
        }

        $stmt_paging = $connect->stmt_init();
        if($stmt_paging ->prepare($sql_query)) {
            // Bind your variables to replace the ?s
            if(empty($keyword)){
                $stmt_paging ->bind_param('ss', $from, $offset);
            }else{
                $stmt_paging ->bind_param('sss', $bind_keyword, $from, $offset);
            }
            // Execute query
            $stmt_paging ->execute();
            // store result 
            $stmt_paging ->store_result();

            $stmt_paging->bind_result($data['Menu_ID'], 
                    $data['Menu_name'], 
                    $data['Category_name'],
                    $data['Price'], 
                    $data['Serve_for'],
                    $data['Menu_image'],
                    $data['Quantity']
                    );

            // for paging purpose
            $total_records_paging = $total_records; 
        }

        // if no data on database show "No Reservation is Available"
        if($total_records_paging == 0){

    ?>
    <h1>Товары не доступны
        <a href="add-menu.php">
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Добавить товар</button>
        </a>
    </h1>
    <hr />

    <?php 
        // otherwise, show data
        }else{
            $row_number = $from + 1;
    ?>
    <div class="container">


        <h1>
            Товары 
            <a href="add-menu.php">
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Добавить товар</button>
            </a>
            <hr/>
        </h1>


    </div>
    <form class="list_header" method="get">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="pholder">Поиск по названию: </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" />
    </div>
    <br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnSearch" value="Поиск" />
    </form>
    <!-- end of search form -->
    <br/>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
    <table class='table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered'>
        <tr class="success">
            <th>Изображение</th>
            <th>Название/Цена</th>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        // get all data using while loop
        while ($stmt_paging->fetch()){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="6%"><img src="<?php echo $data['Menu_image'];?>"width="100" height="180"/><td><?php echo $data['Menu_name'];?> 
            /<?php echo $data['Price']." ".$currency;?>
                </a>&nbsp;
                <a href="menu-detail.php?id=<?php echo $data['Menu_ID'];?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn" value="Посмотреть" name="btnEdit" />
                </div>

                </a>&nbsp;
                <a href="edit-menu.php?id=<?php echo $data['Menu_ID'];?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn" value="Изменить" name="btnEdit" />
                </div>

                </a>&nbsp;
                <a href="delete-menu.php?id=<?php echo $data['Menu_ID'];?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn-primary btn" value="Удалить" name="btnEdit" />
                </div>
                </a>
                </td>


    <?php } }?>



        <?php 
            // for pagination purpose
            $function->doPages($offset, 'menuM.php', '', $total_records, $keyword);
        ?>
    </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="separator"> </div>
</div> 


<?php 
    $stmt->close();
    include_once('includes/close_database.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: Вы серьёзно думаете что кто-то будет все это смотреть?

Comment: 1) Подумайте что меняли. 2) Подумайте что могло поменяться ( от вас не зависящее) 3) Ваш вопрос больше похож на задачу для фрилансера. И как бы не видно собственно ошибку. Не работать может по разному.

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц  я работал только с одним из каталогов а есть ещё каталоги за которыми закреплены базы. В них я уже давно ничего не менял и особо не работал с ними а они тоже глючат на поисковике . Что за глюк понять не могу.

Comment: var_dump никто не отменял. Поставьте 10 контрольных точек и посмотрите что не так